# tag count on collection

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I want to copy feature from stackexchange sites: every time you have list of questions, on the right side there is a list of all tags presented in them, including their count (frequency).
Is there any performance friendly way, how to obtain this kind of information without iteration through every element in view? Let's suppose it should work with common view data source, and content of the view can be altered by filter (keys, category) or fulltext.
I have already have considered (and refused) few solutions:

Iterate through collection - unusable for performance reasons (especially if ViewNavigator can't be used - FT query).

Counting tags in rendered content - limited to visible page only, tags for other pages are not counted (stackexchange counts tags for every page). Good performance though.

DocumentCollection.intersect - iteration through all tags and intersecting collections of all documents with that tag against source collection would result in count of documents with such tag. This approach is performance killer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a categorized view with a summary column and query it in json. Needs to be collapsed. ?ReadViewEntries&Outputformat=json

Comment: This would work if I wanted all tags of all documents under some specific category. What I want is all tags of "any" collection - for example result of FT search.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider two basic approaches:

1. Store the tags in a multi-value summary text field in your question documents, create a categorized view based on that field, open the view, create a NotesViewNavigator, use CreateViewNavFromCategory to create a NotesViewNavigator that only contains the documents that match the tag, and get the NotesViewNavigator.count() property value.
2. Store the tags in a field (it can be multi-valued or single-valued, summary or non-summary text or even a rich text field) in your question documents, full text index the database, and use the Database.FTSearch method with a search formula that uses the FIELD keyword to get a NotesDocumentCollection, and use the NotesDocumentCollection.count() property.

For filtering, I think the latter approach may be better.  You might be able to just revise your FT query to include additional conditions to accomplish the filtering.  This could be very flexible, and should be pretty fast.  With NotesViewNavigator, on the other hand, you would have to iterate through the NotesViewEntry objects in order to do the filtering.